# Error installing tizen studio on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

No matter which of the three tizen studio 2.0 installers I try they all don't work as they won't accept any path. The CLI installer gives the most detailed description:

> ** The directory you specify is not allowed to install the Tizen Studio. Some tools of the Tizen Studio will not properly work in the directory with administrator privilege or read-only access rights for your account.=> *path*

I have tried starting the installer with admin rights and owning the destination folders. Additionally, I switched from JDK 9 to 8.

Still, there seems no way to get the installer running. Any ideas what the reason could be? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to install tizen studio web-ide into Windows 10 64bit OS. Install was succesfull and I can launch studio. Install path is default C:/tizen-studio FYI, I am using Win10 Enterprise N, OS Build 15063. It runs in Oracle VM Virtuala Box. Before installing tizen studio, I installed JDK 8u151. Hope this info will be useful somehow.

Comment: Strange thing it works for you but not for me.. However, I am not the only one having the problem

Comment: I've also installed Tizen-Studio 2.0 on windows 10 x64 Successfully, No similar 'Target Directory Invalid' issue. Have to Identify first in which exact scenario such error is being shown.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to install tizen studio and the SDK using the %appdata% path.
If anyone else has the problem, try e.g.

> C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\Samsung\tizen-studio

This is definitely a flaw Samsung should take care of!

Answer (score 11):

I've successfully installed the IDE version with the following method:

1. Download Tizen Studio Web IDE installer
2. Open installer with 7-zip archive manager
3. You should find tizen-sdk.zip archive
4. Open it and extract it into the C:\tizen-studio folder
5. Create C:\tizen-studio-data folder
6. Create sdk.info file inside C:\tizen-studio folder
7. Put following lines into this file

   TIZEN_SDK_INSTALLED_PATH=C:\tizen-studio

   TIZEN_SDK_DATA_PATH=C:\tizen-studio-data
8. You can download packages with C:\tizen-studio\package-manager\package-manager.exe
9. You can start IDE from C:\tizen-studio\ide\TizenStudio.exe

This worked for me, hope this helps...

Answer (score 4):

*@Henry* was almost correct and his scenario works on CLI/IDE installers.

And here are actual restrictions on Win10x64 tizen-studio 2.0 installation I've found:

- pointed SDK location needs to be in your user directory. For example:

> *C:\Users\MrSmith\Tizen\tizen-studio*

- Data location could be anywhere, but in case of CLI installation, it will be near SDK folder.
- CLI installation actually does unzip only and all further system configuration needs to be done manually. So, if you need only CLI, you could unzip "web-cli_Tizen_Studio_2.0_windows-64.exe" with 7zip or any other proper archiver where you want and do further manual configuration. (See here https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/cli)

Probably, if you login under Administrator you will be able to install SDK anywhere. Just "Run as administrator" doesn't work, at least for me.

*My system params:*

- *Win10 Pro x64*
- *Oracle JDK 1.8.0_152*

Have a fan ;)

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem that way:

- create folder (eg Tizen_Studio)
- inside created folder create new (tizen_studio and tizen_studio_data)
- add all permissions for that folders for your windows account user
- select folders in installation proccess

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The regular way which Samsung provides is working for me:

- Make sure you have enough disk space (Tizen Studio needs about 700 MB
  on Win10)
- Create an **empty** folder with 2 **empty** subfolders (e.g. Tizen_IDE->studio (subfolder #1) -> data (subfolder #2)

The important part on Windows 10 is to navigate to YOUR users directory:
For example your user name is Bob. Go to C:\ -> Users -> Bob. 
Then create there the empty folder "Tizen_Studio" with the 2 mentioned subfolders.
Check with right-clicking on the Tizen_Studio folder -> Properties -> Security if your Username (here Bob) is listed in groups and users. Click on your profile there in the security tab and look if the folder has full access rights inside the checkboxes (btw this should be automatically set if you choose the right described environment).

Now in the installer dialog you can choose the studio folder for the ide/sdk and the data folder for the installing data request path.

Thats it! Just important to install it **inside** your username folder!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well (on my Windows 8.1 machine), and ended up using the previous version of Tizen Studio Installer (version 1.3)

https://download.tizen.org/sdk/Installer/tizen-studio_1.3/

Answer (score 0):

It even does not work for me in %APP_DATA% and also not running the installer with Administrative privileges.
But I finally found a solution which worked for me:

1. Create a new and folder somewhere
2. disable all inherit privileges  on this folder
3. grant explicit all privileges for your users to this folder
4. remove all other privileges, especially these for Administrator
5. Use this folder for Installation
6. Write useful sofware for tizen ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How bout removing 32 bit Java client and installing 64 bit on win 10?
Worked for me, no one seemed to notice that Installer opened in 7zip has an installer.jar which needs to be run with java client.
Thanks for the advises on opening installer with 7zip.